# gphoto2 Script in localhost php

Tags: linux, camera, lamp, libgphoto2

I am trying to run gphoto2 command in LAMP on Ubuntu 15.
This is my PHP script c.php:

```
<?php
    exec('gphoto2 --capture-image',$message);
    print_r($message);
?>
```

When I run this on terminal it works fine, but when I run it in browser with http://localhost/mycam/c.php it does not execute.

Comment: Well, running it on a terminal and in a browser isn't really the same thing. What you can try is running it in a terminal logged in as the web server's user.

Comment: True, but other gphoto2 commands are giving similar output in browser as they give on terminal.